# Android repositioning view, wrong y-value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to move a view from one RelativeLayout container to another RelativeLayout, named transparentOverlay in the code below. (*The other one is an overlay, which I intend to use to make my animations on*).

This is my layout structure:

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:id="@+id/rootLayer"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding">
   <!-- The value of activity_padding is 16dp -->

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    ....
   </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Transparent layer -->   
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/transparentOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
int[] prevLocForView = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(prevLocForView);

RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) rootLayer.findViewById(R.id.transparentOverlay);
int[] rlLoc = new int[2];
rl.getLocationOnScreen(rlLoc);

rl.addView(view);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.leftMargin = currentLocForLetterView[0] - rlLoc[0];
layoutParams.topMargin = currentLocForLetterView[1] - rlLoc[1];
```

It get displayed at the correct position in the container, however, it returns a wrong y-value from the following code:

```
int[] temp = new int[2];
view.getLocationInWindow(temp);
```

The x-value is correct, but the y-value was previous 370 and is now 24 (which is the same value as `rlLoc[1]`).

Another thing is that the view gets smaller in width and larger in height, compared to the original view.

What's the reason for this? What do I need to do to get this right?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this is not the same issue than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069733/how-to-force-view-to-recalculate-its-position-after-changing-parent), but [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082767/1430607) might the same.

I did a simple test. with this backgammon board.

[image: a backgammon board draft with some chips in a point]

Then:

1. Move the first chip in the left (the red one in the bottom) to the right point
2. Move the second chip in the left (the blue one in the bottom) to the right point
3. Move the third chip **to the first position of the right point**

So, it goes

```
4          0     --->     4          3
3          0     --->     0          1
2          0     --->     0          2
1          0     --->     0          0
```

[image: backgammon after moving chips around]

As you see, results are not OK, all the chips keep the original position within their previous parent.

On the other hand, the View is being added and the chips are being displayed properly (you can see two red chips in a row, because of the third move)

Actually this happens because just putting the chips in the right point doesn't make them force their layout. You need to **add an onLayoutChangeListener to the view you're moving so you can react to the layout change after it has been performed, and so, after you've gotten the final position**:

```
public class YourView extends View {
private int[] currentLocation = new int[2];
/*.....
  * blah,blah,blah
  * .....*/

public void init() {
    this.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            int[] newLocation = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(newLocation);
            Log.d("New location:", "("+newLocation[0]+","+newLocation[1]+")");
            /** Do whatever is needed with old and new locations **/
            currentLocation = newLocation;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is always related to the view's parent.
So, you have to calculate the new y-value position, and set. You can't just use the same.

Comment: That's what I did: params.topMargin = prevLocForView[1] - flLoc[1];
And if I check the value of topMargin it's the correct value, 370.

Comment: From FrameLayout doc: The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits). So, you should calculate and use padding, instead of margin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The view do get displayed at the correct position. However, when I check getLocationInWindow() for the moved view, the X-value returned is correct, but not the Y-value.

And how come I need to add the value 8 on the width and height when creating the View?