# How to force View to recalculate it's position after changing parent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

It has been some days since I have this problem.

This is a reformulation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228834/android-repositioning-view-wrong-y-value/31047856#31047856) considering the behavior I describe on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047856/1430607). Please, note that this question states for a less specific case, and the answer could be useful for many different scenarios.

I'm moving one chip from the left point to the right point, and writing original and new coordinates:

[image: backgammon before][image: backgammon after]

So this is failing:

```
public void onTouch(View view) {
    int[] aux = new int[2];

    //Get the chip
    View movingChip = findViewById(R.id.c1);
    //Write it's coordinates
    movingChip.getLocationOnScreen(aux);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.p1t1)).setText("(" + aux[0] + "," + aux[1] + ")");
    //Move it
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.p1)).removeView(movingChip);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.p2)).addView(movingChip);
    movingChip.requestLayout();//#### Adding this didn't solve it

    //Write it's coordinates
    movingChip.getLocationOnScreen(aux);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.p2t4)).setText("(" + aux[0] + "," + aux[1] + ")");
}
```

When I get the coordinates for the second time, I get the coordinates of the view as if it was **positioned in the new parent at the same place it was in the old one**

So, new top, left, bottom, right etc... are not being calculated at this point.
On the other hand, my views are displayed properly, so this job is getting done at some point. How could I force this calculation to happen ?

I need to do it this way, because I'll want to trigger a transition animation

Comment: [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) that view. which will cause it to redraw

Comment: which one? the new parent?

Comment: the one for which you need co-ordinates for

Comment: Didn't work. Actually, I'm changing this position in an onTouch event, and if i invalidate it will be redrawn after the end of my code, which is already being done.

Comment: show your code of `onTouch()` event

Comment: postInvalidate doesn't work neither. The code is the one in the question

Comment: `postInvalidate` is used when you are invalidating it off UI Thread.

Comment: Try `movingView.requestLayout()`. BTW, you are moving `movingView` but last coordinates that you are reading are from `movingChip`

Comment: My original code says movingChip, I changed it for clearness. requestLayout is not working, maybe because I may be going through a layout pass already, and it will not have the time to perform the new layout request before I get the new coordinates...

I changed my question for a better visual explanation

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Then Dalija should post it, I don't want to get credit for her answer

Comment: I don't know what am I supposed to do in this case, I'm taking a look to the SO rules again, I guess, thanks

Comment: I saw your edit yesterday, but it was late and I didn't have time to respond. I would have also suggested that you add your solution as answer and not edit to the question, like @Code-Apprentice did. Especially, since my answer was not full blown solution but more pointer in right direction.

Comment: Answering your own question is certainly an accepted practice here at SO. This is especially appropriate when you have a complete solution that differs significantly from those given by other answers. Even if an answer pointed you in the right direction, but is incomplete in some way, you are fine posting a more complete answer. You can always give a link to the answer which you drew inspiration from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution based on Dalija's suggestion

```
public class ChipView extends ImageView {
    private int[] currentLocation = new int[2];
    /*.....
      * blah,blah,blah
      * .....*/

    public void init() {
        this.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                int[] newLocation = new int[2];
                v.getLocationOnScreen(newLocation);
                Log.d("New location:", "("+newLocation[0]+","+newLocation[1]+")");
                /** Do whatever is needed with old and new locations **/
                currentLocation = newLocation;
            }
        });
    }
```

So, init() is called from the constructor; now I'll try to perform the animation from there, but this is a different tale.I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `OnLayoutChangeListener` to capture your chip movements. Of course, you will have to attach those listeners outside `onTouch` event

```
    chip.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: That's a great idea, but how do I get the previous parent position like this?

Comment: I want to perform an animation like this one:

                    //Remember that the chip is already in the destination point
                    int deltaX = origCoordinates[0] - destCoordinates[0];
                    int deltaY = origCoordinates[1] - destCoordinates[1];

                    TranslateAnimation chipMove = new TranslateAnimation(deltaX, 0, deltaY, 0);

Comment: I think I found the answer here, I'll give it a look and post the answer if that's what I'm looking for
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/09/19/crossing-boundaries-with-the-new-android-viewoverlay/

Comment: It worked, I'll append my final solution to the question, its better than the proposed solution in the related question which suggested to override onLayout, I can keep track of the old position via a private attribute.